# Remove empty lines

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to remove empty lines from a text file using a Windows Batch file.

**Original file**:

```
Test 1234
Test 12

Test 11

Test 1134
```

**Modified file**:

```
Test 1234
Test 12
Test 11
Test 1134
```

*Note that the first line in the original file was also an empty line.

I have tried this, but does not really do anything:

```
for /F "delims=" %a in (file.txt) do echo %a
```

Comment: Does ```(for /F "delims=" %a in (file.txt) do if {%a}=={} (echo %a)) > newfile.txt``` work?

Comment: `DOS` doesn't have `for /f`. Are you speaking ot the Windows Command Line (`cmd`) instead? (then please adapt the tags) Also within a batch file, you need `%%a`. `%a` is directly on the command line only (both `DOS` and `cmd`)

Comment: @NekoMusume: `for /f` already ignores empty lines, so there is no need for `if`

Comment: `findstr /v "^$" file.txt` (not in `DOS` though)

Comment: If you are really working on [tag:dos], you won't succeed with `for /F` as the `/F` option is not supported…

Comment: a safer variant (but not safe) of @Neko's, `@FOR /F useback^ tokens^=*^ delims^=^ eol^= %L in ("test.txt") do @echo(%L`, lines over 8191 characters will be skipped.

Comment: @NekoMusume when running I get the error: `a} was unexpected at this time.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is:

```
@echo off
if exist "file.txt" %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R "^." "file.txt" >"file.tmp"
if exist "file.tmp" for %%I in ("file.tmp") do if %%~zI == 0 (del "file.tmp") else move /Y "file.tmp" "file.txt"
```

**FINDSTR** runs a regular expression find for lines which have at least one character at the beginning of the line and so **FINDSTR** outputs all lines not being empty. The output by **FINDSTR** is redirected into temporary file `file.tmp`.

The created temporary file replaces the input file on being created at all (input file exists) and is not empty which means at least one non-empty line found in input file. The temporary file is deleted on being created, but being an empty file.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `move /?`

See also the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of the redirection operator `>`.